# Api Facebook - Function upload albums

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create an album through my web, using the Facebook Api.
With my developer user it works fine, but with another user not (is about permissions issue).
I am trying to debug my code, but when I call this function: 
`facebook->api("me/albums","POST",array("name"=>$name,"message"=>$message,"privacy"=>$privacy));`
My project stops and the others functions in my project, dont execute.

I want retrieve this error to control this call.
I mean, if the user haven´t the permissions, i want that my project keep running the others functions.

Thanks so much, I hope your help.

Comment: Step 1: Configure your PHP error reporting properly, so that it can tell you what is wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12772851#12772851 Step 2: Catch the exceptions the SDK might throw properly.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot this, i supose i am very saturated with this issue, and i can´t think clearly, :-(

Comment: Check if your FB App is in developer mode. You need to make it public in order to allow other people to use your App.